# Which of the following is definitely false?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, graphing-functions

[image]

The graph of the $f(x)$ function is given above.

According to this graph, which of the following is **definitely false?**

A) $\lim_{x\to -2}f(x)=1$

B) $\lim_{x\to 2^+}f(x)+\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=4$

C) $f(x)$ is defined at $x=2$

D) $\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x)+\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=7$

E) $\lim_{x\to -2}f(x)+f(2)=-1$

---

My attempts:

At first, I couldn't understand the difference between false and definitely false.

A) is correct. Because, $\lim_{x\to -2^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to -2^-}f(x)=1$.

B) I get, $\lim_{x\to 2^+}f(x)+\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1+2=3$

C) is correct. Because, it is black for the circle.

D) I get

$\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x)+\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=5+2=7$

E) I get

$\lim_{x\to -2}f(x)+f(2)=1+1=2$.

---

Thus, several options are definitely false.  ( B and E). Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: "At first, I couldn't understand the difference between false and definitely false." The way I see it, you have a graph. Reading off a graph is never accurate. Thus you can't evaluate whether a statement is true or false. But you can determine whether a statement "could be true" or "is definitely false". For instance: Is $f(0)=2$? I don't know. But it looks like it _could_ be true. Is $f(0)=3$? Unless they are trying to trick us, that's definitely false.

Comment: Add to the trickery: the scale in the $y$-direction seems pretty funky to me!

Comment: For the purpose of this exercise, think of "definitely false" as "there is no way to argue that it is true". Can you edit the question to include precisely which ones you think are definitely false?

Comment: @Bonnaduck Yes, B and E are definitely false, I think.

Comment: @Bonnaduck I fixed Thank you.

Comment: Couldn't the answer be "B and E"?

Comment: Is the circle at $(2,1)$ really black inside? It seems ambiguous; it looks like a pencil might have touched the paper inside the circle, but whoever made the graph did not seem serious about making it black inside the circle.

Comment: @B.Goddard Then, the question is wrong...

Comment: @DavidK You are absolutely right. Black circle seems not enough black. Otherwise, C and E are automatically wrong..

Comment: Since we are not certain that the circle is fully black, we can't say that C) is *definitely* false.

Comment: I think we can probably agree that the statement "this is a good problem" is **definitely false**...

Comment: We can't see the directions for the problem.  If the directions indicate "mark all that apply"  then it's a fine question.  If the directions say "mark only one" then there's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your answers:

A) Correct, it looks true.
B) Correct, it is definitely false.
C) Correct, it looks true.
D) Correct, it looks true.
E) Correct, it is definitely false.

Looks good.

Comment: Thank you (+1), so the question is wrong, right?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Because only one of the options must be correct.

Comment: The question doesn't say that only one of the options is definitely false.

Comment: I mean it's an exam question.  Only one option should be correct.  Otherwise, the question contains errors.

Comment: I've taken exams with "circle all correct answers" in it. In any event, if you are certain that there is only supposed to be one correct answer, then yes, the exam has a mistake.